# How to convert Latin-1 character to ascii (Python)

Tags: python, string, ascii

I've a problem with some strings in python.

I want to convert a string like this: "sanità" , in this one: "sanit%e0" in order to use it into an URL.

I tried everything on internet using different library (like .encode and .decode) but none of them worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Why Latin-1 and not UTF-8?

Comment: Cause i've to use this type of data in my country

Comment: Most browsers use UTF-8 for url-quoted non-ASCII values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.quote) method:

```
urllib.quote(u'sanità'.encode('latin1'))
'sanit%E0'
```

Notice that the output of `urllib.quote` will be encoding dependent. For example with a `cp437` encoded string the output would be `sanit%85`. But well, `urllib.quote` will do that kind of scaping.

Comment: Now i've a new prob xD The string "sanità" is saved into a variabile. How can i add the "u"?

Comment: @TheNobleSix The `u` was to indicate that I was turning a unicode into latin1. If you're source code is already encoded in latin1 (or your variable is encoded in latin1) you don't need the `u` nor the `encode` function. Just try with `urllib.quote(var)`